# Not able to open MS outlook in Windows 7 Home premium

Tags: windows-7, microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2007

I have installed MS Office suit in my laptop (OS: Windows 7 Home Premium). it worked really fine. just a month ago, when I turned on my laptop.. it has prompted me to check for errors.. it took me to dump physical memory.. process went fine. later, when I logged in & tried to open my MS outlook suite. I see this error.

[image]

I even tried uninstalling the MS office setup & installed 2010 setup. even then, it din work.. it has prompted d same error window.

did someone face this issue in Windows7 before? please suggest me a solution to make my MS outlook work as earlier.

Comment: Have you tried System Restore back to a date it was working properly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Checking for errors means that your computer turn off not safe (perhaps battery was empty). 
This error says that .pst file is damaged due to shutdown.

Reinstalling Outlook didn't help because Outlook always left this file on computer after uninstalling.

If you have restore point on your laptop, you could restore this file, otherwise I advise you just delete this file and recreate account in Outlook.

1. Close Outlook
2. Press <kbd>Win</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd>
3. Insert this into window and press OK

   ```
   %userprofile%\Local Settings\Application Data\Microsoft\Outlook
   ```
4. In explorer delete corrupted .pst file
5. run Outlook

Comment: hi KTF, Thanks for your comment. I have followed the procedure, located the corrupt pst file & deleted it. but, when I run outlook.. it says 'the file C:\users\prax\appdata\local\microsoft\outlook\outlook.pst can not be found". Can you guide me further? your comment was of great help

Comment: KTF, thanks again. It has prompted me to create a new pst file & I did. outlook has started working as earlier. thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Find the repair tool scanpst.exe and scan the problem PST.  In some cases the tool cannot recover and so data will likley be lost.  I usually make a backup before the repair attempt.

It is a bit "hidden" so you will need to check the following folders
for Outlook  2007

32-bit Windows

C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office\Office12

64-bit Windows

C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Office\Office12

For Outlook 2010

32-bit Windows

C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office\Office14

64-bit Windows

C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Office\Office14

64-bit Outlook

C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office\Office14